# IPv6 Tunnel For Ubuntu

Tags: server, .desktop, grep, ipv6, localhost

Hi Dear Friend I Want Run IPv6 tunnel Between 2 Ubuntu and Forward Traffic ipv4 I test Gre tunnel

Error: an IP address is expected rather than

Gre in Ubuntu Donnot support ipv6 For local And Dst address for tunnel

Whitch Tunnel In ubuntu support Ipv6 For local And dst Addreess
My internet have only ipv6 address
Please help me

Comment: Called RFC 7040    https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100055377/845fbfa5/configuring-an-ipv4-over-ipv6-tunnel

Comment: There is no question here. Also the tags make no sense for what is written here or the title. From your question "Gre in Ubuntu Donnot support ipv6 For local And Dst address for tunnel" What is this?

Comment: I need Tuunel That Forward Traffic ipv4 Over tunnel ipv6 My internet only support ipv6 Now I want Config tunnel and Forward Traffic Ipv4  How Can do this By ubuntu ???

Comment: Please update the title and the body of the question to say that. Also add what you have already done to reach that goal.